# MultiMap Challenge: Javascript reduce method syntax error?

Tags: javascript, methods, reduce

I have the following challenge:

> Construct a function `multiMap` that will accept two arrays - an array of values and an array of callbacks. multiMap will return an object whose keys match the elements in the array of values. The corresponding values that are assigned to the keys will be arrays consisting of outputs from the array of callbacks, where the input to each callback is the key.

The code given with the challenge:

```
// Uncomment these to check your work!

function uppercaser(str) { return str.toUpperCase(); }

function capitalize(str) { return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase(); }

function repeater(str) { return str + str; }

const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];

const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];

console.log(multiMap(items, functions)); // should log: { catfood: ['CATFOOD', 'Catfood', 'catfoodcatfood'], glue: ['GLUE', 'Glue', 'glueglue'], beer: ['BEER', 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }
```

My Solution

```js
function multiMap(array, callbacks) {
  const emptyArray = [];
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    array.forEach(element => {
        while (callbacks.length) {
          emptyArray.push(callbacks(element));
        }
      }
      return acc[current] = emptyArray
    )
  }, {})
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!

function uppercaser(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

function capitalize(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function repeater(str) {
  return str + str;
}

const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];

const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];

console.log(multiMap(items, functions)); // should log: { catfood: ['CATFOOD', 'Catfood', 'catfoodcatfood'], glue: ['GLUE', 'Glue', 'glueglue'], beer: ['BEER', 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }
```

My Problem:

I am trying to push myself to use methods more often in solving challenges. Every time I attempt using the reduce method, I run into syntax error. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong in this particular problem?

Comment: what is `while (callbacks.length) {}`? won't it be an infinite loop?

Comment: In `reduce()`, the value returned by the callback will be the next value of `acc`. You're returning `emptyArray` each time. Normally you modify `acc` and then return it.

Comment: Not sure about syntax errors, but you definitely have several runtime errors. Like this one: `callbacks(element)`. `callbacks` is an array, it's not a function, your code attempts to call it

Comment: you should use `callbacks.map()` somewhere, since you want to get a list of the results of each callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need both `array.reduce()` and `array.forEach()`. The first one will loop over the array. Inside that you should use `callbacks.map()` to get a list of the results of each callback.

The `reduce()` callback function must return `acc` after updating it.

```js
function multiMap(array, callbacks) {
  return array.reduce((acc, current) => {
    acc[current] = callbacks.map(callback => callback(current));
    return acc;
  }, {})
}

// Uncomment these to check your work!

function uppercaser(str) {
  return str.toUpperCase();
}

function capitalize(str) {
  return str[0].toUpperCase() + str.slice(1).toLowerCase();
}

function repeater(str) {
  return str + str;
}

const items = ['catfood', 'glue', 'beer'];

const functions = [uppercaser, capitalize, repeater];

console.log(multiMap(items, functions)); // should log: { catfood: ['CATFOOD', 'Catfood', 'catfoodcatfood'], glue: ['GLUE', 'Glue', 'glueglue'], beer: ['BEER', 'Beer', 'beerbeer'] }
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much, it just clicked for me after days of trying to understand.  I was getting the logic behind reduce confused and trying to recreate the .map method in a poor way. Thanks again!